# Python program, user friendly query

Tags: python, python-3.x

I saw your bit explaining how to import these things and generate a random number using them but can you solve this problem. This is (the starting stages of) my program:

```
import random
from operator import add, sub, mul
for x in range(10):
    ops = (add, sub, mul)
    op = random.choice(ops)
    num1, num2 = random.randint(1,10), random.randint(1,10)
    int(input("What is %s %s %s?\n" % (num1, op, num2)))
    ans = op(num1, num2)
```

However when I execute this code this is printed: What is 8  1?
and I was wondering how I would efficiently print this in a user friendly way such as:
"What is 8 add 1?"

Thankyou if you solve this!

Comment: @Cyber though it should be noted that the relevant answer in that duplicate is [yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26261125/1599111), not the accepted one. The OP has already seen the light and is using the `operator` module instead of `eval`, so mapping the functions to the symbols in a dict is the next logical step ;-)

Comment: Do you want it as "**What is 8 add 1?**" or "What is 8 plus 1?" because it's working fine. [ideone.link](http://ideone.com/o1jIEN)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use a dictionary instead of a tuple.

```
import random
from operator import add, sub, mul
for x in range(10):
    ops = {'+': add, '-': sub, '*': mul}
    op = random.choice(ops.keys())
    num1, num2 = random.randint(1,10), random.randint(1,10)
    int(input("What is %s %s %s?\n" % (num1, op, num2)))
    ans = ops[op](num1, num2)
```

Comment: after pasting this solution into python you get this error:          Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users//Documents/Random.py", line 5, in <module>
    op = random.choice(ops.keys())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/random.py", line 256, in choice
    return seq[i]
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing            Whats wrong with this??

Comment: In python3, change `opts.keys()` to `list(opts.keys())` because in py3 `dict.keys` is an iterator, and `random.choice` needs to know the length, and does not automatically evaluate iterators (as it should not).

Answer (score 1):

As Luke said, op.**name** would print the operator used. If you want explicit +/-/* or added to, multiplied by/subtracted from you can refer [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/o1jIEN)

```
if op == mul:
        int(input("What is %s %s %s?\n" % (num1, 'multiplied by', num2)))
elif op == add:
        int(input("What is %s %s %s?\n" % (num1, 'added to', num2)))
elif op == sub:
        int(input("What is %s %s %s?\n" % (num1, 'subtracted from', num2)))
else:
        print ("randomise error, sorry.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply changing

`(num1, op, num2)`

to

`(num1, op.__name__, num2)`

does what you're asking for. Of course, you'll probably want to print `+`, `-` or `*`, and that will require a simple `if/elif` structure. I'll let you figure that out ;D