# Random Arithmetic Quiz Problems

Tags: python, random

Im having trouble with a simple python quiz that randomly generates the answers and operators I'm fairly new to python and this is as complex as I can get, The program will run with no errors but will not do anything any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code (taken from [How can I randomly choose a maths operator and ask recurring maths questions with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260950/how-can-i-randomly-choose-a-maths-operator-and-ask-recurring-maths-questions-wit/26261125#26261125)):

```
import random
import time

def randomCalc():
    ops = {'+':operator.add,
           '-':operator.sub,
           '*':operator.mul,
           '/':operator.truediv}
    num1 = random.randint(0,12)
    num2 = random.randint(1,10)    
    op = random.choice(list(ops.keys()))
    answer = ops.get(op)(num1,num2)
    print('What is {} {} {}?\n'.format(num1, op, num2))
    return answer

def askQuestion():
    answer = randomCalc()
    guess = float(input())
    return guess == answer

def quiz():
    print('Welcome. This is a 10 question math quiz\n')
    score = 0
    for i in range(10):
        correct = askQuestion()
        if correct:
            score += 1
            print('Correct!\n')
        else:
            print('Incorrect!\n')
    return 'Your score was {}/10'.format()
```

Comment: @Cyber Why didn't you call the function in your answer. The OP is disgusted with you ;)

Comment: @BhargavRao I'm sorry! I'm driving over to their computer right now to type it for them!

Comment: @Cyber: Wow, that explains it! (I couldn't help wondering how the OP could write such high-quality code yet not know how to call it.)

Comment: @Cyber That is the best solution. Better do it fast. Also ask the OP, as to how `operator` became `time`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the `quiz()` function at the top level of your code:

```
quiz()
```

You're also missing:

```
import operator
```

Answer (score 1):

Call your functions by adding a call statement at the end.`quiz()`

Python is not like C or any other language which automatically calls the `main` method

As NPE spotted, you have changed `import operator` to `import time`. Change it back.