# How could I change this Maths quiz in order to not use eval to find the answer in Python?

Tags: python, eval

I heard `eval` was very bad practice in Python because of security issues.
So I was wondering if there is a way I could not use `eval` in this program.

```
for _ in range(10):
    n1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    n2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    operator = random.choice("+-*")
    question = (n1,operator,n2)
    questionNo +=1
    useranswer = input(question+" = ")
    answer = eval(question)

if useranswer == str(answer):
    correct += 1
    print('Correct!Your score is, ", correct)
else:
    print('Wrong Your score is, ", correct)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260950/how-can-i-randomly-choose-a-maths-operator-and-ask-recurring-maths-questions-wit/26261125#26261125

Comment: this looks amazingly simillar to this earlier question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681164/python-questionnaire

Comment: note that in this SPECIFIC case, `eval` is not dangerous. `eval` only creates a security concern when you combine it with unsanitized user input. Since completely sanitizing user input is incredibly difficult, it's safe to treat it as a security concern when you combine it with ANY user input. However there's no user input being `eval`'d here.

Comment: Or I suppose with computer-generated random strings that might end up malicious. The infinite monkey theorem shows that `eval(''.join[random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '/\\()\'"[]{};') for _ in range(1000)])` will eventually write a program that will destroy your computer completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a mapping from the symbol of the operator to an actual function that represents that operator:

```
import operator as op
operator_map = {"+":op.add, "-":op.sub, "*":op.mul}
```

then just change to

```
answer = operator_map[operator](n1, n2)
```