# Python maths quiz random number

Tags: python, loops, math, random

hello i am trying to make a code for a random maths quiz generator i have it so it randoms the number and the operations but i cant get it to repeat 10 times as i want it to ask 10 questions can someone help please here is my code

```
import random
import time

name=input("What is your name?")
print ("Alright",name,"Welcome to your maths quiz")
score=0
question=0
finish= False
ops = ['+', '-', '*']
rand=random.randint(1,10)
rand2=random.randint(1,10)
operation = random.choice(ops)
maths = eval(str(rand) + operation + str(rand2))
print ("Your first question is",rand,operation,rand2)
question=question+1
d=int(input ("What is your answer:"))
if d==maths:
    print ("Correct")
    score=score+1
else:
    print ("Incorrect. The actual answer is",maths)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260950/how-can-i-randomly-choose-a-maths-operator-and-ask-recurring-maths-questions-wit/26261125#26261125

Comment: i have tried a while loop but i dont know what im doing as im very new to python

Comment: You kidding me? You wrote this but you can't figure out how to repeat it 10 times??

Comment: You can use while loop. `while question <= 10:` then rest of your code then `question=question+1` which you already did.

Comment: `for _ in range(5): print('hi')`.

Comment: Use a for loop to execute the code 10 times.

Comment: Off topic: Be careful with `eval()`. It can be very dangerous if it executes user input. (This doesnt seem to be the case in your code.. just saying).

Comment: okay tanveer i am trying the while question but where do i put it as if i put it before print it just prints the question 10 times and other places it misses out the question sorry for seeming so stupid i have never really coded anything before and want to learn with simple things

Comment: Insert **only** the things you want to be repeated in the `while` or `for` loop.

Comment: im still confused can someone edit into the code i supplied please im trying to use a while loop as the for loop didnt work i want it to ask a different question every time but i doesnt work no matter where i put the while question <=10:

Comment: `for` loop should work as well. Anyway, i edited my answer below; now it contains your code the way you (probably) wanted it to work.

Comment: Thank you it what i wanted thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `for` loop:

```
for num in range(5): 
    # Replace "print" below, with the code you want to repeat.
    print(num)
```

---

To repeat all questions, excluding `"whats your name.."` include the part of the code you need in the loop:

```
import random

name=input("What is your name?")
print ("Alright",name,"Welcome to your maths quiz")
score=0

for question_num in range(1, 11):
    ops = ['+', '-', '*']
    rand=random.randint(1,10)
    rand2=random.randint(1,10)
    operation = random.choice(ops)
    maths = eval(str(rand) + operation + str(rand2))
    print('\nQuestion number: {}'.format(question_num))
    print ("The question is",rand,operation,rand2)

    d=int(input ("What is your answer:"))
    if d==maths:
        print ("Correct")
        score=score+1
    else:
        print ("Incorrect. The actual answer is",maths)
```

Comment: How many times `for question_num in range(1, 10):` will run? 10 or 9 ?

Comment: @VivekSable You are right, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Use **while** loop with condition.

Algo:

1. Set `counter` to `0`.
2. Use `while` loop and check `counter` less then `10` or not.
3. Ask question to user.
4. Do your calculation.
5. Increase `counter` by one.
6. When `counter` is equal to `10`, that time `condition` will be `False`.

Demo:

```
>>> counter = 0
>>> while counter<10:
...    que = raw_input("Enter que:")
...    print que
...    counter += 1
... 
Enter que:1
1
Enter que:2
2
Enter que:3
3
Enter que:4
4
Enter que:5
5
Enter que:6
6
Enter que:7
7
Enter que:8
8
Enter que:9
9
Enter que:10
10
>>>
```