# python string operator addition and subtraction error

Tags: python, string, input

I am making a calculation program where randomly chosen operator does addition and subtraction of two numbers the problem is that beside showing '+' or '-' sign, the outcome is `9<built-in function add>7` I am writing the code like this

```
input(num1 + str(operator) + num2, "= ")
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26261125/4014959

Comment: @PM2Ring nah not working

Comment: " not working" is a bit vague. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Use the eval function to get your answer:
[Python eval function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval)

Basically it just evaluates a string for mathematical, etc. operations and functions.

```
answer=eval(str(num1)+"[operator]"+str(num2))
```

So if num1 was 9 and num2 was 7 and your operator was "-", you would end up with:

```
answer=eval("9-7")
```

and it would do the operation and return 2

Comment: the operator is randomly chosen so I don't think this is right

Comment: Yes, get your random operator by doing `random.choice(["+","-","*","/"])` then put that value into where [operator] is.

Comment: I had tried that before but apparently it doesn't work

Comment: Are you getting an error or does it just not work? If so, please tell me what error you are getting

Comment: `    op = random.choice("+", "-") #this variable randomly selects the operator
TypeError: choice() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: Don't forget to use brackets [] since you are selecting an option from an array: `op = random.choice(["+", "-"])`

Comment: I missed it before but still getting the same error by using it @user2525692

Comment: What version of python are you using and what is your _exact_ line of code? Once you import random, you should be able to use the code I posted earlier. @Kutttayqarateraa

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `eval()` unless you know _exactly_ what you're doing. It is actually safe to use `eval()` here, but it can be very [dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) on arbitrary strings. So it's not a good habit to get into using  `eval()`, it's _much_ better to solve problems in a way that doesn't need  it.