# Not sure why, but when I input the correct answer it will still say I got it wrong

Tags: python

I'm new to python and coding in general. I have a problem where I don't think it's using the operator correctly. I was wondering if someone could help.

```
types = ("minus","times","plus","divided by")
q3type = random.choice(types)
if q3type == "minus":
    q3operator = "-"
if q3type == "times":
    q3operator = "*"
if q3type == "plus":
    q3operator = "+"
if q3type == "divided by":
    q3operator = "/"
q3a = random.randint(1,10)
q3b = random.randint(1,10)
print("What is",q3a,q3type,q3b,"?")
q3 = input("Answer: ")
correctAnswer = (q3a,q3operator,q3b)
if q3 == (correctAnswer):
    score = int(score + 1)
    print("Correct!, your score is now:",score)
else:
    print("Oops, you got that one wrong")
```

Comment: The problem is in this line: `correctAnswer = (q3a,q3operator,q3b)`. The left-hand side doesn't magically evaulate the expression - instead, it returns a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) of strings.

Comment: `don't think it's using the operator correctly`. One of the biggest learning curves for new programmers is getting used to the idea that in 99.9999% of cases, when something does not work, it's because **you** are wrong and not the language or library you are trying to learn.

Answer (score 2):

### The Solution

The problem is in these two lines:

```
q3 = input("Answer: ")
correctAnswer = (q3a,q3operator,q3b)
```

`q3` gets a string. `correctAnswer` gets a [tuple of strings](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). When you compare the two, they'll obviously never be equal.

The simplest way to solve this is to change lines to the following:

```
q3 = int(raw_input("Answer: ")) # guarantee q3 is treated as an integer
correctAnswer = eval(str(q3a)+q3operator+str(q3b)) # eval treats a string as Python command
```

This should solve your problem for you.

### How it works

`eval` converts a string into a Python expression and evaluates it - something like "5 + 3" gets converted into the actual expression 5 + 3 and evaluated to yield 8.

I had to convert `q3a` and `q3b` to strings so that I could use `eval` on them - hence why I used `str(q3a)` and `str(q3b)`.

Note that `raw_input` only works on Python 2.7 - `input` is the right thing to use in Python 3.

`eval` is also potentially dangerous if you can't control what you pass to it - it's good in this situation, but the fact you have to use it indicates that there's probably a much better way to write this program. :)

### How you can improve your program

The key to writing good programs is to use the right language constructs for them.

In this case, you can improve your code by utilising two very powerful Python features: [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and [lambda functions](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html). I'll leave you to spend some time reading on what they are and could do.

Here's an example of what your program could look like with these improvements (to keep it simple, let's say you only want simple addition and subtraction problems):

```
functions = {"plus": lambda x, y : x + y, "minus": lambda x, y: x - y}
operation = random.choice(functions.keys())

a,b = random.randint(1,10), random.randint(1,10)
answer = int(raw_input("What is {0} {1} {2}?".format(a,operation,b))

print("Correct!" if answer == functions[operation](a,b) else "Wrong!")
```

Note how much shorter, cleaner and easier it is. You can add arbitrary functions to `functions` and guarantee the rest of the program works perfectly.

Moral: Use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: FYI, the `operator` module contains functions such as `operator.add`, `operator.mul`, etc., so you don't have to use `lambda`.

Comment: That's a good resource too. Just thought lambda would be more pedagogic.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260950/how-can-i-randomly-choose-a-maths-operator-and-ask-recurring-maths-questions-wit) to your problem, including how to turn this into a quiz with multiple questions!

In your example, it would be easy for you to use python's `operator` module. Replace `q3operator = "+"` with `q3operator = operator.add` and so on (see [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260950/how-can-i-randomly-choose-a-maths-operator-and-ask-recurring-maths-questions-wit)). Finally, `correctAnswer = (q3a,q3operator,q3b)` becomes `correctAnswer = q3operator(q3a,q3b)`.
Remember to `import operator` at the top of your code!

You will also need to set `score = 0` at some point (before you attempt to use it on the right side of `score = int(score + 1)`.