# (Python) Generating Numbers then Printing them on One Line

Tags: python, random, numbers, sum

I have an assignment that requires me to print 10 random sums, then get the user to enter their answers. I know how to randomly generate numbers, but I need to print the whole sum out, without giving the answer, but with the string I am using it adds them automatically.

This is my code below:

```
for i in range(10):
        number1 = (random.randint(0,20))
        number2 = (random.randint(0,20))
        print (number1 + number2)
    answer = input("Enter your answer: ")
```

If someone could help me out I would appreciate it, I believe the line

```
    print (number1 + number2)
```

is the problem, as it is adding them when I just want the random numbers printed in the sum.

Thanks in advance,

Flynn.

Comment: Please, start with a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

To convert numbers to a string for concatenation use `str()`.

```
print str(number1) + ", " + str(number2)
```

or using natural delimiter

```
print number1, number2
```

*(The `,` tells python to output them one after the other with space. `str()` isn't really necessary in that case.)*

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
print number1, '+', number2
```

Comment: Or `print("{0} + {1}".format(number1, number2)` for a better control of the formatting.

Comment: How would I randomise the operation in the sum?

Comment: @FlynnJackson Didn't get your question; can you explain?

Comment: @FlynnJackson That's a new question! But anyway, there are several ways to randomly choose an operation. There are  _many_ questions on SO asking about this kind of arithmetic quiz program in Python, eg [How can I randomly choose a maths operator and ask recurring maths questions with it?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26261125/4014959)

Comment: No worries, I randomised it from a list of +, -, *, /. It doesnt seem to be registering their functions, appears as if the answer is wrong even if it is correct... Attempting a score system but it wont go up when it is correct

Answer (score 1):

Your following line first computes the sum of the two numbers, then prints it

```
print (number1 + number2)
```

you have to print a string:

```
print(str(number1) + " + " + str(number2))
```

---

or prefer formating features instead of concatenation:

```
print("{} + {}".format(number1, number2))
```

or:

```
print("%s + %s" % (number1, number2))
```

---

Finally, you may want to read some doc:

- [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.format#str.format)
- [string formatting with the `%` operator](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.format#string-formatting)
- [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
from random import randint

for i in range(10):
  num1 = randint(0,20)
  num2 = randint(0,20)
  answer = input('Sum of %i + %i?: ' % (num1,num2)
```

Perhaps you know what to do with the rest? (e.g. handling the answer section)